# Programmatically getting Micronaut Datasource

Tags: micronaut-data

I am in the midst of incrementally converting a vanilla java app to Micronaut.  As code base cannot be converted all at once, for code base where one can't do @Inject for the datasource, is there a programmatic way of getting the Micronaut datasource that is defined the the application.yml file?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community "is there a programmatic way of getting the Micronaut datasource that is defined the the application.yml file?" has enough detail to identify an adequate answer.  The answer is "yes" and below is some code that shows how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> for code base where one can't do @Inject for the datasource, is there
> a programmatic way of getting the Micronaut datasource that is defined
> the the application.yml file

Yes.  If you have a reference to the `ApplicationContext` you can retrieve the data source.  For example:

```
HikariDataSource dataSource = applicationContext.getBean(HikariDataSource.class);
```